# Multicast socket on Windows 7

Tags: windows, delphi, sockets, multicast, freepascal

this code works fine on Linux and Windows XP, however it always fails to add multicast membership on Windows 7 64bit and Windows Server 2008.

```
uses

  Classes, Sockets,
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows,
  Winsock,
  {$ELSE}
  BaseUnix,
  UnixType,
  {$ENDIF}
   Sysutils;

type
TIP_mreq = packed record
    imr_multiaddr: in_addr;     // IP multicast address of group
    imr_interface: in_addr;     // local IP address of interface
  end;

var
  ASock_Addr : SockAddr_In;
  FSocket    : LongInt;
  ipmreq     : TIP_mreq;
  MasterFD,
  TempFD     : TFDSet;
  TestInt    : Integer;
  Timeout    : TTimeVal;
begin
  FSocket := fpSocket(AF_INET, LongInt(SOCK_DGRAM), 0);
  if (FSocket > 0) then
  begin
    fpSetSockOpt(FSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, PChar('True'), Length('True'));
    FillByte(ASock_Addr, SizeOf(SockAddr_In), 0);
    ASock_Addr.sin_family      := AF_INET;
    ASock_Addr.sin_port        := HtoNS(15510);
    ASock_Addr.sin_addr.S_addr := INADDR_ANY;

    if (fpbind(FSocket, @ASock_Addr, SizeOf(SockAddr_In)) = 0) then
    begin
      FillByte(ipmreq, SizeOf(Tip_mreq),0);
      ipmreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr := StrToNetAddr('224.126.126.126').s_addr;
      ipmreq.imr_interface.s_addr := StrToNetAddr('10.0.0.3').s_addr;
      fpSetsockOpt(FSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,  @ipmreq, SizeOf(ipmreq));
      {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
          FD_SET(FSocket, MasterFD);
      {$ELSE}
          fpFD_SET(FSocket, MasterFD);
      {$ENDIF}
```

fpSetSockOpt in this code will always return -1 on Windows 7 and Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. This is a Freepascal issue related to those operating systems. By changing fpBind and fpSetSockOpt to their Winsock calls (Bind and SetSockOpt) it does work in these operating systems.

Comment: sockets calls winsock2 by default in trunk, with 1:1 parameters, so this is somewhat strange. Maybe you use an older version where it still called winsock. It could also that multicast in Vista+ requires admin rights (try right-click "execute as administrator")